# Creating transparent-like window in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I found a some interesting capture program.
It's so simple, first it creates transparent-like window which cover whole desktop.
And, after you can select area to capture and save to the image file.

I just wanted to know how this program create that kind of transparent window.
Actually, I searched the various way to make window as transparent window.
There are about 3~4 ways to create that.
--- WS_TRANSPARENT, Layered Style, OnColor Message Processing, Etc...

However, according to my analysis on this program, it doesn't use these technics...

I also looked into the resources, but the dialog which cover whole desktop window has WS_VISIBLE and
WS_POPUP style only.
If I add WS_BORDER or WS_DLGFRAME style, then it cannot create the transparent window.
So, I tried to make my own program with a dialog which has same dialog template of the capture program. But it failed.

Lastly, I monitored the program by API-Monitor.
But, Whenever the program create a dialog with createDialogIndirectParam API, 
the dialog created and stayed as transparent status from creation moment.

Does anybody has some thought about this program??...

You can download the capture program from the link (FastCapture)

https: //www.mediafire.com/?rssbh9bz9wvmybw

Comment: The posted link is to a binary with no source given. It might be a virus, or it might be a copy right violation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970066/creating-a-transparent-window-in-c-win32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a window with no border, and process the WM_PAINT and WM_ERASEBKGND messages with functions that don't do anything. Since nothing ever paints the window, it will be invisible.

Note that WS_TRANSPARENT doesn't do what you expect it to. All it does is affect the order of drawing the window with other windows.

Comment: Gee! I'd tried WM_PAINT but, I couldn't think of WM_ERASEBKGND. Thank you so much!

Comment: By the way, since the window doesn't draw or do anything on its client area, so we can't name it as "Transparent" window... right?

Comment: @HyunChanPark I'm not sure what you mean by that question.