# Create a transparent window in C++ Using CreateWindow?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10

Hello people of the internet, I was just wondering is it possible to create a window using `CreateWindow` and also making is completely transparent? This includes the top bar (where the close and minimize buttons are located, idk what its called) and window it self. So the entire "application" I need to be transparent. If you could help that would be amazing, have a great rest of your day/night!

I was looking at [Creating a transparent window in C++ Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970066/creating-a-transparent-window-in-c-win32), but it did not work how i wanted it and is very outdated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a transparent window in C++ Win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970066/creating-a-transparent-window-in-c-win32)

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: You need to say why the linked post (duplicate) does not meet your requirements,  It's still current API and specific questions are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: `SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);` from the linked answer will make the entire window transparent. subsequent `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, 0, 128, LWA_ALPHA);` call will make it 50% transparent. could you be more specific about `it did not work how i wanted`?